# Aquaris E5 after reboot down

Tags: ubuntu-touch

after shutdown -r on my new Aquaris E5 it is down: Black screen and no reaction after using the start bottom. I can't mount it with my Xubuntu 14.04. Here the text is: MTP-Gerät »[usb:002,006]« kann nicht geöffnet werden. I just removed the sim card - no changes.

Any ideas??

Thank a lot
Ali

Comment: Have you tried a hard reboot by pressing the power key for more than 10 seconds? This helped me with my nexus 4 when the system doesn't response.

Comment: Thank you very much. Power down the battery and then reboot with the power connection cable was the solution